# Interface Builder keeps on crashing

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I decided to give iPhone development a try but whenever I open Interface Builder either thru xcode by opening an xib file or manually starting it, the application keeps on crashing. I tried re-installing it multiple times but to no avail. I desperately need your help guys.

Below is the error description from the stacktrace:

```
Process:         Interface Builder [400]
Path:            /Developer/Applications/Interface Builder.app/Contents/MacOS/Interface Builder
Identifier:      com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3
Version:         3.2.5 (823)
Build Info:      InterfaceBuilder-8230000~6
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [229]


*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'IBAssertionFailure', reason: 'Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iPhone Simulator. "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" (380) failed to launch and exited with status 5. Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

Please  help. :(

Comment: Have you tried re-installing all of the SDK or just IB?

Comment: You should file a bug report at bugreport.apple.com and include the crash trace for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool", which you should be able to find in Console.app

Comment: It says quite plainly: 'Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information.' Have you done this? What did you find there?

Answer (score 1):

Did you completely uninstall? Try using this command, if you haven't already:

```
sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

where  is the path to xcode. ie. /Developer

Comment: Hi, Ive tried uninstalling using that command and reinstalling the whole sdk and still the same problem.

Also note that I am starting the IB by cliking the icon and not thru xcode.

Here's the stacktrace from the Console.app
<code>
yld: Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security</code>

Comment: Check to see if the folder /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework exists. If not, that's probably your problem.

Comment: i checked it and it's there :(